# How to make on hover expand background color height on menu

Tags: css

The following is my code

```
<ul class="navbar-nav" style="margin-left: 16%;">

  <li class="nav-item">
    <!-- <button style="background-color: #009688;  height: 25px;"> -->
      <a class="nav-link" style="color: white; font-weight: 500;" href="home.php">Home</a>
    <!-- </button> -->
  </li>

  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" style="color: white; font-weight: 500;" href="about.php">About Us</a>
  </li>

         <li class="nav-item dropdown nav-mod">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="https://bootstrapthemes.co" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" style="color: white; font-weight: 500;">
                            Services
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="panchakarma.php">Panchakarma Therapies</a></li>
                              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="ayurveda_medicines.php">Ayurveda Medicines</a></li>
                              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="diet_consultation.php">Diet Consultation</a></li>
                              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="meditation.php">Meditation</a></li>
                              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="therapy_yoga.php">Therapy Yoga</a></li>
                              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="physiotherapy.php">Physiotherapy</a></li>
                              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="garbh_sanskar.php">Garbh Sanskar</a></li>

                            <li><a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="#">Special Treatments</a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="dhupana_chikista.php">Dhupana Chikista</a></li>
                                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="kumkumadi_facial.php">Kumkumadi Facial</a></li>
                                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="rejuvation_treatment.php">Rejuvation Treatment</a></li>
                                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="relaxation_treatment.php">Relaxation Treatment</a></li>
                                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="suvarna_prashan.php">Suvarna Prashan</a></li>

                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="other_facility.php">Other Facilities we provide</a></li>

                        </ul>
                    </li>


  <li class="nav-item nav-mod">
    <a class="nav-link" style="color: white; font-weight: 500;" href="online_consultation.php">Online Consultation</a>
  </li>

  <!-- <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" style="color: black; font-weight: bold;" href="packages.php">Packages</a>
  </li> -->

  <li class="nav-item nav-mod">
    <a class="nav-link" style="color: white; font-weight: 500;" href="courses.php">Courses</a>
  </li>

  <!-- <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" style="color: black; font-weight: bold;" href="products.php">Products</a>
  </li> -->

  <li class="nav-item nav-mod">
    <a class="nav-link" style="color: white; font-weight: 500;" href="career.php">Career</a>
  </li>

  <li class="nav-item nav-mod">
    <a class="nav-link" style="color: white; font-weight: 500;" href="contact_us.php">Contact Us</a>
  </li>

</ul>
```

I want to make this on like as shown below in the image(Header)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SKSPg.png)

If anyone knows about using CSS please let me help.

The following image shows from my website look.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qAeKT.png)

I want to make my header as shown in first image.

Comment: I encourage you to read about the Google Chrome Developer Tools (https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/css/). You can use this to inspect what Portea is doing to create their navigation menu and replicate the same thing on your website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by using the same line-height for ul, li and a. While you will give the same height for ul, li and a, then it will display the hover height like the menu item height.

```css
nav.navbar.navbar-default {
        background: #288a90;
    }
    
    ul.nav.navbar-nav {
        background: #288a90;
    }
    
    .navbar,
    .navbar ul {
        line-height: 65px;
    }
    
    .navbar ul li a {
        line-height: 65px;
        color: white !important;
        font-weight: 500;
    }
    
    .navbar ul li a:hover {
        line-height: 65px;
        background-color: #fff !important;
        color: #288a90 !important;
    }
    
    .dropdown-menu {
        background-color: #288a90 !important;
        padding: 0;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav" style="margin-left: 16%;">

            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="home.php">Home</a>
            </li>

            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="about.php">About Us</a>
            </li>

            <li class="nav-item dropdown nav-mod">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="https://bootstrapthemes.co" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" style="color: white; font-weight: 500;">
                    Services
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="panchakarma.php">Panchakarma Therapies</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="ayurveda_medicines.php">Ayurveda Medicines</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="diet_consultation.php">Diet Consultation</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="meditation.php">Meditation</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="therapy_yoga.php">Therapy Yoga</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="physiotherapy.php">Physiotherapy</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="garbh_sanskar.php">Garbh Sanskar</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="#">Special Treatments</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="dhupana_chikista.php">Dhupana Chikista</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="kumkumadi_facial.php">Kumkumadi Facial</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="rejuvation_treatment.php">Rejuvation Treatment</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="relaxation_treatment.php">Relaxation Treatment</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="suvarna_prashan.php">Suvarna Prashan</a></li>

                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="other_facility.php">Other Facilities we provide</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>

            <li class="nav-item nav-mod">
                <a class="nav-link" href="career.php">Career</a>
            </li>

            <li class="nav-item nav-mod">
                <a class="nav-link" href="contact_us.php">Contact Us</a>
            </li>

        </ul>

    </nav>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: How to add the same thing for drop down link?

Comment: Here I edited my answer for drop down link also. You can follow the same process for drop-down menu.

Answer (score 0):

you're just putting the background on the anchor (a) tag right?
you probably need to put in the li tag, but i'm not sure, if it dont work please edit your question and put the css file too or use the codepen

Answer (score 0):

I have done some changes, some unnecessary css and made css according to bootstrap to make sure when you add your css file (after bootstrap css file) you don't have to use `!important`

```css
nav.navbar.navbar-default {
        background: #288a90;
    }
    
    ul.nav.navbar-nav {
        background: #288a90;
    }
    
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
        line-height: 65px;
        color: #fff !important;
        font-weight: 500;
    }
    
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover {
        background-color: #fff !important;
        color: #288a90 !important;
    }
    
    .dropdown-menu {
        background-color: #288a90 !important;
        padding: 0;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav" style="margin-left: 16%;">

            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="home.php">Home</a>
            </li>

            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="about.php">About Us</a>
            </li>

            <li class="nav-item dropdown nav-mod">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="https://bootstrapthemes.co" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" style="color: white; font-weight: 500;">
                    Services
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="panchakarma.php">Panchakarma Therapies</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="ayurveda_medicines.php">Ayurveda Medicines</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="diet_consultation.php">Diet Consultation</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="meditation.php">Meditation</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="therapy_yoga.php">Therapy Yoga</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="physiotherapy.php">Physiotherapy</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="garbh_sanskar.php">Garbh Sanskar</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="#">Special Treatments</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="dhupana_chikista.php">Dhupana Chikista</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="kumkumadi_facial.php">Kumkumadi Facial</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="rejuvation_treatment.php">Rejuvation Treatment</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="relaxation_treatment.php">Relaxation Treatment</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="suvarna_prashan.php">Suvarna Prashan</a></li>

                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="other_facility.php">Other Facilities we provide</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>

            <li class="nav-item nav-mod">
                <a class="nav-link" href="career.php">Career</a>
            </li>

            <li class="nav-item nav-mod">
                <a class="nav-link" href="contact_us.php">Contact Us</a>
            </li>

        </ul>

    </nav>

</body>

</html>
```